# geolocation iPhone

Tags: iphone

i have a Map view witch contain several object (Annotation) i would like when i click in one annotation it show to me the zoom ( maximum) of the object (annotation) in an other view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can get is that you want an image to be displayed when you select an annotation in different view which is referred as callout.

The following link might give you what you need, you might still need to customize it, you can also download sample code from there.

http://blog.asolutions.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-1/